# How can i reverse container radius to specific form

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the simple following code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {      
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 100,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black,
              borderRadius:  BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),)
          ),

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

the outputs looks like following
[image]

but i am trying to reverse it to be like following (sorry for the bad drawing)

[image]

How could i achieve this with simple way ? **best regards :)**

Comment: simple way? not really, you need a custom `ShapeBorder` class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a container with inverted rounded corners in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464707/how-to-make-a-container-with-inverted-rounded-corners-in-flutter)

Comment: pskink .. depends on @PixelToast answer yes it is simple .

Comment: @MohammedHamdan custom painter or custom shape are the same things when it comes to complexity - with custom shape you have a lot more pluses thou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html):

[image]

```dart
class InvertedRoundedRectanglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  InvertedRoundedRectanglePainter({
    required this.radius,
    required this.color,
  });

  final double radius;
  final Color color;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final cornerSize = Size.square(radius * 2);
    canvas.drawPath(
      Path()
        ..addArc(
          // top-left arc
          Offset(0, -radius) & cornerSize,
          // 180 degree startAngle (left of circle)
          pi,
          // -90 degree sweepAngle (counter-clockwise to the bottom)
          -pi / 2,
        )
        ..arcTo(
          // top-right arc
          Offset(size.width - cornerSize.width, -radius) & cornerSize,
          // 90 degree startAngle (bottom of circle)
          pi / 2,
          // -90 degree sweepAngle (counter-clockwise to the right)
          -pi / 2,
          false,
        )
        // bottom right of painter
        ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
        // bottom left of painter
        ..lineTo(0, size.height),
      Paint()..color = color,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(InvertedRoundedRectanglePainter oldDelegate) =>
      oldDelegate.radius != radius || oldDelegate.color != color;
}
```

You can play with this example on DartPad: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=18cfbcc696b43c7c002a5ac3c94dd520

Comment: thank you @PixelToast for this awesome answer . you hit it .

Comment: How to call your code under build method as final output  ?

Comment: Use the CustomPaint widget, see the dartpad for an example of how to do that

Comment: oh ok my bad didn't see the link