# How can I modify an image to have a rounded corner and an inverted rounded corner in flutter

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WbP5.png)

Hello everyone!

I really want my **image** to look like the attached preview image with a rounded corner and an inverted rounded corner.

Thanks in advance!

I've tried this: [How can i reverse container radius to specific form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73757422/how-can-i-reverse-container-radius-to-specific-form)

Comment: can you include your current code-snippet ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Franklin Diaz was so helpful! Thanks a lot for it! I changed only one line of code in InvertedRoundedClipper:

```
//Start in the left top corner
path.moveTo(0, 25);
//rounded the top left corner
path.quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, 25, 0);
//line to the right -25 top corner
path.lineTo(size.width - 25, 0);
//rounded the top right corner
path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 0, size.width, 25);
//line to the right bottom corner
path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);

//inverse rounded the top right corner
path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width, size.height-25, size.width-25, size.height-25);

//line to the left bottom corner
path.lineTo(25, size.height - 25);

//rounded the bottom left corner
path.quadraticBezierTo(0, size.height - 25, 0, size.height - 50);

//close the path
path.close();
return path;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need use ClipPath and CustomClipper

Here is an example with the shape you need.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Material App',
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 300,
              height: 300,
              child: ClipPath(
                  clipper: BoxCustom(),
                  child: const Image(
                    image: AssetImage('src/example.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class BoxCustom extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();

    //Start in the left top corner
    path.moveTo(0, 25);
    //rounded the top left corner
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, 25, 0);
    //line to the right -25 top corner
    path.lineTo(size.width - 25, 0);
    //rounded the top right corner
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 0, size.width, 25);
    //line to the right bottom corner
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);

    //line to the 25 up
    path.lineTo(size.width - 25, size.height - 25);

    //line to the left bottom corner
    path.lineTo(25, size.height - 25);

    //rounded the bottom left corner
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, size.height - 25, 0, size.height - 50);

    //close the path
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  ///The moment this [shouldReclip] return false
  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: see at this to create the shape you want.

https://medium.com/flutter-community/paths-in-flutter-a-visual-guide-6c906464dcd0

Comment: It is a brilliant solution, but I really wanted to round the bottom right corner as well.

Comment: change line 48:
    path.lineTo(25, size.height - 25);

to:

path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width - 5, size.height - 25, size.width - 25, size.height - 25);